# BEM: the separation of blocks from layout

Tags: css, bem

Let's say I have to define a header block in BEM. Headers need some indentation (padding, margins), but it's also a common understanding that layout should stay separated from components.

The question is, should I specify indentation as a part of my header block CSS, or should it only be provided by surrounding blocks (layout blocks or grid)? Both approaches have their cons and pros.

Comment: So what are, in your opinion, the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2):

You can mix few blocks (or block and element of some other block) on the same DOM-node.

E.g. `<div class="header layout__header">`.

Comment: I used such a method in my blog http://varya.me/. You can see in the source the 'island' block, not pure layout but somehow responsible for that. Then, its elements can be mixed with other blocks. <div class="article__text box__island">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you specify indentation to header block, because you will need less work to do and will maintain consistency.